# Producer is sending in a localDateTime format and consumer is receiving as array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following situation:

My producer is sending an java object that contains a localdate field in a local date time format:

```
private LocalDateTime dtEmissao;
```

And is sending in producer as a localdatetime object as is supposed to be:

```
2023-04-05T08:42:41
```

However in my next application, im receiving in the consumer in the string message as an array of integers!

```
"dtEmissao":[2023,4,5,8,39,36],
```

Why is it converting a LocalDateTime iinto an array of integers?
How do i fixed that?
Should i fix on the receiving application or the producer application?

This is my configuration of the object mapper on the receiving application:

```
 @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        // StdDateFormat is ISO8601 since jackson 2.9
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

Comment: Removed Kafka/Spring tags since you should be able to reproduce this as a [mcve] by manually constructing your object and using `getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString()` to see the same

Comment: Also, this bean is for Spring's internal ObjectMapper. Kafka uses its own ObjectMapper, if not overridden as well, such as using `spring-kafka` JsonSerializer

Answer (score 0):

That format is `year=2023,month=4,day=5` ... The only thing that is "wrong" there is your minutes and seconds.

You can refer the [Jackson `datetime` module documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) on how this can be modified.

If you want to keep as a formatted date, then make your POJO use String instead, and parse your `LocalDateTime` types separately from your serialization framework.